# SSO and/or JWT: make sure web app's endpoints are protected

Tags: oauth, jwt, sso

Let's say I'm building a web application (let's focus on the backend side) that is B2C. Users should be able to register with my application, using a SSO provider like Google or Facebook. Once they're registered, they can access other endpoints, but all the endpoints should check that the users are authenticated.

These SSO providers (please correct me if I don't use the proper terminology) will provide an OAuth flow: two endpoints will respectively start the flow, and finish the flow (the so-called callback). In the callback endpoint, I'll be getting information like:

- The user's email
- The user's name
- An access token

A lot of articles on the web will describe how to implement the oauth flow, but not what to do next, and I'm looking for guidelines here.

How can I use this access token to make sure my users are authenticated when they access other endpoints? I can envision two ways to do it, but I'm just guessing:

- Use the access token provided by the SSO provider. For every request hitting an endpoint, check that the token in the request's header is valid. To check it's valid, I'd need to query the right provider (e.g: Facebook, Google) every time. This looks like a lot of unnecessary external calls
- In the callback endpoint after the OAuth flow, I could build a JWT token from the user's email/name. It's then easy to check every request because I don't need any external call to do that

Could you tell me what's the "traditional" way to do this please?